# Three students are chosen at random from a class of ten girls and twelve boys

Tags: probability

Three students are chosen at random from a class of ten girls and twelve boys. What is the probability that at least one is a boy given at least one is a girl.

Would this be an independent or dependent event? I believe is dependent since they are not replacing their picks thus the pool gets smaller.

If that is the case then would it be $P(A\cap B)$= P(A) * P(B|A)? I'm thinking probability of ate least one boy is P(A)=$\frac{6}{11}$, and probability of at least one girl is P(B)= $\frac{5}{11}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of boys chosen among the three. You have $X\sim\text{Hypergeometric}(22,12,3)$. Then:

$$P(\text{at least one girl})=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=\frac{6}{77}+\frac{27}{77}+\frac{33}{77}=\frac{66}{77}$$

$$P(\text{at least one boy and at least one girl})=P(X=1)+P(X=2)=\frac{60}{77}$$

$$P(\text{at least one boy}|\text{at least one girl})=\frac{P(\text{at least one girl and at least one boy})}{(\text{at least one girl})}=\frac{10}{11}$$

Comment: So essentially we just find the probability of getting girls and just subtract it by one to get the probability of at least one boy?

Comment: I think the first part is not correct..

Comment: Coudn't fix it, so I deleted it completely.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of selections in which at least one child is a boy given that at least one child is a girl is
\begin{equation*}
\binom{10}{1}\binom{12}{2} + \binom{10}{2}\binom{12}{1} = 660 + 540 = 1200 .
\end{equation*}
The total number of selections in which at least one child is a girl is
\begin{equation*}
\binom{22}{3} - \binom{10}{3} = 1540 + 120 = 1420 .
\end{equation*}
So, the probability that a child selected is a boy given that one of the children selected is a girl is
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1200}{1420} = \frac{60}{71} .
\end{equation*}